# how to make command run concurrently when programming shell scripts?

Tags: linux, shell, concurrency, build

i need download two project, namely A and B, the final result is the build of B project, but it can only be build for project A is installed.

so the tasks i should finish is as follows:

1. download A
2. download B
3. build A, then install A
4. build B, then install B

1 and 2 can run concurrently, 
2 and 3 and run concurrently,

the traditional way to program is:

```
1 && 3
2 && 4
```

is there better ways to program shell, which can finish much more quickly?

```
( (1 && 3 )  & 2 )  && 4    // is there possible? or will this be quicker than the former one?
```

so what is the way to make these task run concurrently?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the traditional way, putting each &&-list in the background (thanks to William for pointing out the correct dependencies to me):

```
1 && 3 &
2 && wait && 4
```

First we run the list `1 && 3` in the background. Job 3 will only start once job 1 completes successfully.

Next, start a new list in the background. This list runs job 2, and if it succeeds, calls `wait`, which will wait for *all* background jobs to finish. (I don't quite see the exact sequence, but it appears that it will not wait for the background job of which it is part. That's good, since you'd have a case of deadlock where a job is waiting for itself to complete. UPDATE: the second list must run in the foreground, so that the `wait` command sees the background command as a background job.) After jobs 1, 2 and 3 all complete, `wait` completes successfully and job 4 begins.

Comment: This may run 4 before 3 completes.  But building B requires A to be installed.  Try `1 && 3 &; 2 && wait && 4`

Comment: When the second sequence is run in background, the `wait` is a no-op, isn't it, because the sub-shell has no child processes running asynchronously?  So, in fact, as William suggested, the second command chain must be run without the final `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the background, then use wait:

```
1&
2&
wait
3&
4&
wait
```

If you give wait a PID or job spec, then it will give you the exit status for logic.

Comment: what %1 and %2 stand for, in wait %1 %2?

Comment: Sorry...I edited my answer. %1 would be a job spec ala shell. The first job you put in the bg. You can also use a PID which is in $! after putting a job in bg.

Comment: A single call to `wait` will wait for both 1 and 2; similarly for 3 and 4.

Comment: A single wait with no argument waits for all child processes to complete.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler wait ls
bash: wait: `ls': not a pid or valid job spec,why it's not valid job spec?

Comment: I stand corrected. I was thinking of the system call...waiting for one in bash requires the pid or job spec.

Comment: @hugemeow: A job spec starts with a `%`; if you want to wait for `ls`, then you'd use `wait %ls`.  If you want to wait for a specific PID, you'd use `wait $!` (to wait for the most recent command executed in the background to terminate) or `wait 23917` to wait for PID 23917 to complete.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  wait %ls
bash: wait: %ls: no such job, why?

Comment: @hugemeow: Presumably because you don't have an `ls` running in background that isn't complete yet; it's already been waited for.